# get element N from array_count_values php

Tags: php

I have an array on which I did array_count_values, and then an arsort.

$a example: `$a = array('ten','ten','ten','three','two',one','ten','four','four');`

I want to get the first element, and tried `$a[0]` but this did not work.

What is the correct syntax to get the first element please?

EDIT - added array
EDIT2 - Also, underlying array not allowed to be changed because their is code following that uses the associative array...

Comment: Please, put your array in your post.

Comment: looks like it should work. maybe something else went wrong. print_r($a) and see what's in your array.

Comment: just a note...OP's example array is numeric but array_count_values() returns associative array where keys are the values of the target array, so the question is really in regards to getting the first array element in an associative array.

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct Crayon Violet

Answer (score 1):

depending on whether or not you want to alter the array, you can use array_slice() or array_shift()

Comment: This changes the underlying array by removing an element which will damage the rest of the code which uses the array later...sorry

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_values as

```
$a = array_values($a);
```

var_dump($a[0])

Answer (score 1):

Same as in your last question.

```
key($a);    // or each() for the first key=>value pair
```

Or alternatively:

```
$k = array_keys($a);
print $k[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

ok I used this:

```
$a = array('ten','ten','ten','three','two','one','ten','four','four');
$bb= array_count_values ($a);
arsort($bb);
echo reset($bb);
```

It only works for getting the first element...Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways of getting the first element:

- $next = $arr[0];
- $next = array_shift($arr);
- $next = current($arr); // if the internal cursor is at position 0